# Unable to find 2FA tab under security tab in store configuration

Tags: security, magento2.4.2, 2fa

I want to enable 2FA for admin login in Magento 2.4.2 but it is missing.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the below extension in enabled mode.

> Magento_TwoFactorAuth

```
php bin/magento module:status Magento_TwoFactorAuth
Magento_TwoFactorAuth :  Module is disabled
```

If not, we can enable it by below command.

```
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
```